# jQuery: Exclude Checkbox with a specific value

Tags: jquery, checkbox

How to exclude checkboxes like

`<input type="checkbox" value="multiselect-all">`

from

`$(section).find('input, select').each(function(i, field) {});`

I tried using

`$(section).find('input:not(checkbox), select').each(function(i, field) {});`

but it didn't work at the first place. So I could not proceed to filter checkbox with a value.

Comment: Do you want to filter out all checkboxes, checkboxes with the specific value of `multiselect-all`, or all checkboxes that have any value?

Comment: All the checkboxes with the value of `mutiselect-all`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about:

```
$(section).find('input:checkbox:not([value=multiselect-all]), select').each(function(i, field) {});
```

Answer (score 1):

Think you can use filter to filter out all inputs/select that arent a checbox with the specific value of "multiselect-all":

```
$(section).find('input, select').filter(function() {
    return !(this.type === "checkbox" && this.value === "multiselect-all");
}).each(function(i, field) {});
```